# How to insert date while importing Excel into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I loaded an Excel file into SQL Server and it's working fine, but I want to attach current date while importing this file. That means each row will have the date data loaded in. So each time I load the file, new data should take the current date, and the old data still have the old date.

How can I do that ?

Code for importing the Excel file:

```
string ssqltable = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
string myexceldataquery = "select * from [" + ssqltable + "$]";

try
{
    OleDbConnection oconn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + imagepath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");

    string ssqlconnectionstring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Bioxcell;Integrated Security=true";

    OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(myexceldataquery, oconn);
    oconn.Open();

    SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ssqlconnectionstring);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(oledbcmd.ExecuteReader());
    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = ssqltable;

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(i, i);
    }

    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dt);
    oconn.Close();
}
```

and this for inserting date but not working for me

```
if (ssqltable == "Overseas")
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand sqlc = new SqlCommand("delete from Overseas where Bonus = 'Bonus'", conn);
    sqlc.ExecuteScalar();

    SqlCommand Update1 = new SqlCommand("Update Overseas set ID = 1 Where ProductCode = 9630", conn);
    Update1.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlCommand Update2 = new SqlCommand("Update Overseas set ID = 2 Where ProductCode = 9628", conn);
    Update2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlCommand Update3 = new SqlCommand("Update Overseas set ID = 3 Where ProductCode = 9629", conn);
    Update3.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlCommand Update4 = new SqlCommand("Update Overseas set ID = 4 Where ProductCode = 9632", conn);
    Update4.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlCommand Update5 = new SqlCommand("Update Overseas set ID = 5 Where ProductCode = 9631", conn);
    Update5.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlCommand Update6 = new SqlCommand("insert into Overseas (Date) Values (GETDATE())", conn);
    Update6.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

No error and only one date was inserted. How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have control over the table, you can create a new date column with a default value of `GETDATE()`:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename>
ADD ROW_CREATE_TS DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-default-values-for-columns

Comment: every row added it will take current date ?

Comment: Correct. Link to the MS doc [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-default-values-for-columns)

Comment: nice .. it's worked but how can i make date format like 12/4/2017 ? :D

Comment: Depending on your SQL server version you can use one of the following commands in your SELECT statement

`FORMAT( <column_name>, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-US' )`
or for older versions [CONVERT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

`CONVERT(nvarchar(30), <column_name>, 103)`

Comment: my sql server version is 2008 how can i do it from design  ?

Comment: `CONVERT(nvarchar(30), <column_name>, 103)`

Comment: tried this but doesn't work .. how table name doesn't exist ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141594/discussion-between-matt-m-and-amr-kamal).