# SQL import excel add current date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I would like to import an excel sheet to SQL using the import wizard and add an additional column to the table which has the current date.

**For example:**

In Excel, I have the following:
Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4

In the SQL Table I would like: Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 and an additional Col with the current date.

The table has all 5 columns with the 5th column a datetime datatype.  I will delete the rows in the destination table before importing.

Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357768/how-to-insert-date-while-importing-excel-into-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert date while importing Excel into SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357768/how-to-insert-date-while-importing-excel-into-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a default value of `GETDATE()` to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[yourTable] 
      ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_yourDate]  DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [yourDate]
```

Then just exclude `yourDate` column from inserts.

Answer (score 2):

When using Import Wizard you have the option of writing a query to specify the data transfer.  This is adding the current datetime to a load from Sheet1.

```
    SELECT *,NOW() AS LoadDt FROM `Sheet1$`
```

LoadDt was placed first in data mapping, so in editing the SQL in that tab just moved that column to the end.

Comment: Using `NOW()` instead of `GETDATE()`for Excel SQL is the main thing.